# Insert row over existing row, move rows down

Tags: sql

I'm trying to insert a new row in the middle of a sql table and move all other rows first to make space for it.

I've tried 
`setting id=id+1`, 
but that gives me an error(obviously) because the row `id+1` exists already, so this only works for going in the other direction so `id=id-1.`

What is the correct solution then?

Comment: Why should you do such thing? If you want to store sequenced order, use separate field for that. `id` is a primary key and in common case it may not contain sequence

Comment: It's going to be a small table (under 100 rows) and it's easier for me to work with it like this under phpmyadmin.

Answer (score 1):

To do the stuff, you should update you table from the end:

```
UPDATE `table` SET `id`=`id`+1 WHERE `id`>$value ORDER BY `id` DESC
```

Where $value is your value

Answer (score 0):

You could try something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name SET id = id + 1 WHERE id >= your_id_value ORDER BY id DESC;
INSERT INTO table_name(..., id, ...) VALUES(..., your_id_value, ...)
```

Comment: No, you will get error: `Duplicate entry '$entry' for key 'PRIMARY'` - because rows are updated one by one